# In Mojave Filemaker access by applescript throws privilege Error

Tags: applescript, privileges, filemaker

I have an applescript which reads a cell from filemaker. Since Mojave (OS 10.14) it fails with

**error "FileMaker Pro 18 Advanced got an error: A privilege violation occurred." number -10004**

I assume it has to do with the security features of Mojave. How can I fix this?

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro 18 Advanced"
    tell document "test.fmp12"
        tell table "customerTable"

            set customerName to data of cell "nameOfCustomer"

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

the set command throws the error. 
In System Preferences/Security & Privacy/Privacy 
I gave full disc access to Script Editor and Filemaker Pro Advanced

Answer (score 0):

did you go to File menu/Manage/Security and edit the Privilege Set to Allow Apple Events for the FMP file?